# Grunt message: Fatal error: Port 35729 is already in use by another process

Tags: node.js, grunt-contrib-watch

Grunt was working. But after moving my site's files up one directory, to sit at root, grunt stopped working:

Fatal error: Port 35729 is already in use by another process.

Would the path matter in this case? Looking at port 35729, I found that Grunt was the only process running on that port. I killed that process, confirmed that no other process was running on 35729, then ran grunt again, but still getting that same fatal error as before.

Although none of my config files changed for grunt since it was working, I thought I'd try using the "npm init" approach to create a new package.json, then run "npm install" again and confirmed it downloaded "node_modules". What else can I try?

I'm running Node v0.10.33 on Mac OS 10.10.5

Comment: Random thought but I think Sublime text uses Port 35729, if you have that open then kill that :) (or you can change it in preferences)

Comment: Grunt is the only process on that port. Sublime Text had always been open before without conflict with Grunt.

Comment: Check livereload in Sublime text:

Sublime Text 2 > Preferences > Package Settings > Live Reload > Settings - User

Paste in: {
    "port" : 35730
}

Comment: That will override the existing settings - just try it :)

Comment: I don't have Live Reload as a package in Sublime Text 2, so nothing to override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Although grunt-cli is installed globally, grunt gets installed locally with the project. So when I moved my site's files up one directory, and ran grunt from that new location, I was effectively launching a second instance of grunt, which found the port already occupied  of course, by the earlier instance of grunt launched before moving files.

After I killed that process, grunt ran without a problem. I wasn't able to kill it using kill -9 so I used the Mac's Activity Monitor to issue "Force Quit".

Answer (score 37):

Dont stop a process with `Ctrl+C` in the terminal.

`Ctrl+Z` will keep it running.

Find the process id by `sudo lsof -i :35729`

Then kill the process by `sudo kill -9 PID`

Rerun the grunt watch

Comment: if its a docker issue just close and re-open a ssh sesh

Answer (score 5):

Grunt watch was already running in a different project in my case. So I updated Grunt's watch task appropriately for live reload to watch on a different port.

```
 watch: {
        main: {
            options: {
                livereload: 35730,
                livereloadOnError: false,
                spawn: false
            },
            files: [createFolderGlobs(['*.js', '*.less', '*.html']), '!_SpecRunner.html', '!.grunt'],
            tasks: [] //all the tasks are run dynamically during the watch event handler
        }
    }
```

Specified `livereload:PORT`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `grunt-contrib-watch`'s live reload: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/blob/v1.0.0/tasks/lib/livereload.js#L19

You can't have two grunt-watch with the `livereload` option set to true. Either set one of the `livereload` options to false or change the port of liverelaod to something else by setting the `livereload` option from `true` to other value than 35729, like `live-reload: 1337`.

See the docs for more: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#optionslivereload

Otherwise, you can run as many grunt processes as you want.

Answer (score 0):

solution :

### Step 1

Run command-line as an Administrator. Then run the below mention command. Type your port number in `yourPortNumber`:

```
netstat -ano | findstr : (yourPortNumber)
```

[image]

### Step 2

Then you execute this command after identify the PID.

```
taskkill /PID  (typeyourPIDhere) /
```

---

Enjoy Coding !